# Is it possible to zip and replace in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Im writing a gradle plugin, that is responsible for creating a release zip, my question is; is it possible to zip all the contents of a directory and replace the contents with the created zip. I had tried a couple approaches but all seem to fail or overwrite themselves.

The closest I could get was:

```
private void zipCurrentWorkSpace(ZipReleaseDTO packageDTO) {
    String stagingDir  = getProject().getBuildDir() + ZipReleaseConstants.OUTPUT_DIR;
    String tmpDir = getProject().getBuildDir() + ZipReleaseConstants.TMP_OUTPUT_DIR;
    
    this.getProject().copy(copySpec -> copySpec.from(stagingDir).into(tmpDir));

    Delete deleteStaging = getProject().getTasks().create(DELETE_STAGING_TASK, Delete.class);
    deleteStaging.delete(getProject().fileTree(stagingDir).exclude(tmpDir));

    deleteStaging.getActions().forEach(action -> action.execute(deleteStaging));

    Zip zip = getProject().getTasks().create("zipReleaseZipper", Zip.class);
    zip.from(tmpDir);
    zip.setProperty("archiveName", packageDTO.outputName);
    zip.setProperty("destinationDirectory", getProject().file(stagingDir);
    zip.getActions().forEach(action -> action.execute(zip));

    Delete deleteTmp = getProject().getTasks().create(DELETE_TMP_TASK, Delete.class);
    deleteTmp.delete(getProject().fileTree(tmpDir));
    deleteTmp.getActions().forEach(action -> action.execute(deleteTmp));
}
```

where I copy all the files from a staging dir over to a tmp dir, wipe the staging dir, zip the contents from the tmp dir back to the staging, then wipe the the temp dir. Although the last deletion seems to fail and delete everthing. I have tested until that point and seems to be working as expected! Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same effect?

Note: I am creating a couple tasks on the fly here because I have a wrapping task that is managing numerous tasks in order to create a release package.

Note2: Im not sure if its worth mentioning but I ran into some difficulties when trying to zip to the same location, coincidentally my final zip name and a zip component in the staging directory have the same name.

Comment: Why is it necessary to wipe stagingDir in the first place? Doing that will break up-to-date checking.

Comment: @BjørnVester This logic is called recursively, so I need to keep moving files between two dirs in order to zip and replace the staging dir.